# Alsa does not recognize my sound card Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I've tried to reinstall Alsa and pulseaudio multiple times with reboots. I've tried editing /etc/modules but to no avail.

[link](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/404419) to a bunch of logs [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) asked me to generate If you ask, I will get you more.

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

returns

```
--- no soundcards ---
```

And in the ubuntu sound manager it says only output is a dummy output.

If it helps, I'm on a new lenove 310 ideapad laptop.